# Angular 9 Dialog window does not open after select filters

Tags: angular, typescript

on the page, open a dialog box, then close and select filters
(  </...></...>).

After selecting filters, the dialog does not open. but in dev-tools I see that the dialog window is initialized (loaded if necessary components from the back-end or something is executed (tested with log lines to the console in OnInit)).

this is how i open the dialog:

openDialog(data, dialog, width = DIALOG_DEFAULT_WIDTH) {
const openedDialog = this.dialog.open(dialog, {
data,
width,
closeOnNavigation: true,
});
this.subs.push(openedDialog.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
if (result) {
this.refresh();
}
}));
}

html:
<button mat-raised-button (click)="onCreateClick()" [disabled]="notValidForm(item)">Test

```
openCreateDialog() {
    this.openDialog({data}, dialog);
}
```

In dialog component i call methods if they need.

Hope u can help me.

Comment: Can you clarify more, what "third library" you are using for modal or dialog manipulation, and did you got an error can you share your dialog code?

Comment: import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';

Comment: export class Component extends PortalDialogComponent<Component> implements OnInit {


 constructor(protected dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Component>,
    protected globalService: GlobalService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
 ) {
  super(dialogRef, globalService);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

Comment: filters nz-select nz-options

Comment: if we first select filters, then the dialog window opens correctly. but if we open dialog and then select filter -> dialog don't open